# wsgen generating WSDL using @WebMethod but ignoring @WebParam

Tags: java, wsdl, wsgen

I'm generating a WSDL from a Java class using the `@WebService`, `@WebMethod` and `@WebParam` annotations. The WSDL is generated, and includes output for `@WebService` and `@WebMethod`, but the `@WebParam` annotations appear to be ignored.

Here's one method declaration with this problem:

```
@WebMethod(action = "jmsServiceInitialise")
public boolean jmsServiceInitialise(
        @WebParam(name = "queue") String queueName, 
        @WebParam(name = "channel") String channel, 
        @WebParam(name = "hostname") String hostName, 
        @WebParam(name = "port") String port, 
        @WebParam(name = "requiresresponse") boolean requiresResponse) {
    log.info("jmsServiceInitialise " + queueName + ": started");
    // etc
    return returnValue;
}
```

The WSDL file contains no mention of any of the parameters, but the method is there. The method can be called as a web service, but the String parameter values are all `null`.

I originally encountered this problem in Eclipse, but have since replicated the problem with wsgen at the command line (Windows, JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01) and get the same result.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add `@WebResult` annotation to method, after `@WebMethod` annotation
and
make `@WebMethod(operationName = "jmsServiceInitialise")` instead of *action*